# Is there the list of identifiers of the apple devices on the official site?

Tags: ios

Is there the list of identifiers of the apple devices (see the printscreen attached) on the official site (like developer.apple.com) ?
I saw such a list on wikipedia and other sites (in different terms of actuality), but I can't find it on the official site.
You can get in code such an identifier as follows:

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

[image: list]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the iPhone Wiki is your best bet for this kind of thing. I have no idea why you want this information (if you're writing an app and looking at this, that's a bad idea), but it should all be there. If it's not, [ipsw.me](https://ipsw.me) probably has a list too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And why is that a bad idea? I want to obtain the model of device. What is an alternative?

Comment: @Max If you’re just using it for analytics, that’s fine. If you’re enabling/disabling features based on it, that’s not fine.

Comment: yep, for analitics on server side